# Spring Data Elastic Search with Nested Fields and mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch and elasticsearch together to query documents. I'd like to do nested queries on nested documents.

I have this in java :

```
@Document(indexName = "as", type = "a", indexStoreType = "memory", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
class A {

     @Id
     private String Id;

     @Field(type = String, index = analyzed, store = true)
     private String field1;

     // ... Many more Fields.

     @NestedField(type = FieldType.Object, index = analyzed, store = true, dotSuffix = "accounts")
     private List<B> bs;

     // ... getters and setters
}
```

And

```
class B { // some normal pojo }
```

When I let spring-data do the mapping, I get :

```
"a": {
    "properties": {
        "bs": {
            "properties": {
                "someBProperty": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "BId": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "id": { ... },
        ...
}
```

When I am trying to query the document, I get the classical inner vs nested documents problems and it doesn't recognize the nested element.

When I try to update mapping to use nested document I get "can't be changed from non-nested to nested".

Should I tell spring-data-es somehow that @NestedField => type: "nested" into mapping ? Is there a way to add custom mapping to spring-data when it create index & mapping ?

Also, I am initializing indexes via :

```
elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(A.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(A.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(A.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(A.class,true);
```

And then querying using spring-data repository :

```
QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery( "bs", QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("as.field1", "A1")).must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("as.field2", "B1")));

Iterable<DenormalizedRelationshipDocument> res = aRepository.search(builder);
```

Here the res has 0 element in the Iterable but via REST I get the error on the nested query not supported (as I don't have it in mapping).

finally,

Does Spring-Data-ElasticSearch supports nested mappings via ES QueryBuilders API ? When should I make that mapping happens ?

Answer (score 18):

Spring data elasticsearch now supports most of the common feature set of elasticsearch including Nested, Inner Objects and Parent Child(recently)

Detailed explanation can be found at [managing relationship in elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/)

**Nested document Example**

Person Entity

```
   @Document( indexName = "person" , type = "user")

    public class Person {

        @Id
        private String id;

        private String name;

        @Field( type = FieldType.Nested)
        private List<Car> car;

        // setters-getters

    }
```

Car Entity

```
    public class Car {
    private String name;
    private String model;
    //setters and getters 
    }
```

Setting Up Data

```
    Person foo = new Person();
    foo.setName("Foo");
    foo.setId("1");

    List cars = new ArrayList();
    Car subaru = new Car();
    subaru.setName("Subaru");
    subaru.setModel("Imprezza");
    cars.add(subaru);
    foo.setCar(cars);
```

Indexing

```
        IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();
        indexQuery.setId(foo.getId());
        indexQuery.setObject(foo);

       //creating mapping
       elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Person.class);
       //indexing document
       elasticsearchTemplate.index(indexQuery);
       //refresh
       elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Person.class, true);
```

Searching

```
 

    QueryBuilder builder = nestedQuery("car", boolQuery().must(termQuery("car.name",      "subaru")).must(termQuery("car.model", "imprezza")));

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(builder).build();
    List persons = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Person.class);
```

you can find more test cases about Nested and Inner Object at [Nested Object Tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/NestedObjectTests.java)

Comment: can you please suggest a method using @Query annotation for the same.

Comment: Can you please suggest a  method to turn _source off using spring data es ?

Comment: SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withFields() method if you want specific fields only.