# Querying Spring Data Elasticsearch for nested properties

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to query spring data elasticsearch repositories for nested properties. My Repository looks like this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends
        ElasticsearchRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(String zipCode);
}
```

The domain objects Person and Address (without getters/setters) are defined as follows:

```
@Document(indexName="person")
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Field(type=FieldType.Nested, store=true, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
  private Address address;
}

public class Address {
  private String zipCode;
}
```

My test saves one Person document and tries to read it with the repository  method. But no results are returned. Here is the test method:

```
@Test
public void testPersonRepo() throws Exception {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Rene");
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setZipCode("30880");
    person.setAddress(address);
    personRepository.save(person);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Person.class,true);
    assertThat(personRepository.findByAddressZipCodeContaining("30880"), hasSize(1));
}
```

Does spring data elasticsearch support the default spring data query generation?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch indexes the new document asynchronously...[near real-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html#refresh-api?q=refresh). The default refresh is typically 1s I think. So you must explicitly request a refresh (to force a flush and the document available for search) if you are wanting the document immediately searchable as with a unit test. So your unit test needs to include the ElasticsearchTemplate bean so that you can explicitly call [refresh](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java#L981). Make sure you set waitForOperation to true to force a synchronous refresh.  See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831882/spring-data-elastic-search-with-nested-fields-and-mapping?answertab=active#tab-top). Kinda like this:

```
elasticsearchTemplate.refresh("myindex",true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have added elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Person.class,true); but that does not help. However if I do personRepository.findAll() it returns the document.