# filter nested array spring elasticsearch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

i'm using spring data elasticsearch and i indexing this document in elastic

```
{
  "country":{
     "name":"jordan",
     "cities" : [
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"amman"
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "name":"jarash"
        },
        {
          "id":3,
          "name":"aqaba"
        },
        {
          "id":4,
          "name":"salt"
        },
        {
          "id":5,
          "name":"karak"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

so i need to write query to get the country with all cities their names start with 'a' character

so expected result should be :

```
{
  "country":{
     "name":"jordan",
     "cities" : [
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"amman"
        },
        {
          "id":3,
          "name":"aqaba"
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

so how can i achieve that using spring data ?

Comment: I am trying to understand this since at least one week.

Comment: i hope someone has a solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

I think [Spring Data Elastic Search with Nested Fields and mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831882/spring-data-elastic-search-with-nested-fields-and-mapping)
 has the answer to our problems.